# Flutter: How to save multiple values to json?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have a model class for saving last login info

```
class LastLogin {
  @JsonKey(name: 'full_name')
  final String? fullName;
  @JsonKey(name: 'login_date')
  final String? loginDate;

  const LastLogin({
    this.fullName,
    this.loginDate,
  });

  factory LastLogin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LastLoginFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LastLoginToJson(this);

  @override
  String toString() => toJson().toString();
}
```

I use sharedPrefs. So I created PrefsKey `static TypeStoreKey<LastLogin> lastLogin = TypeStoreKey<LastLogin>('LastLogin');` to save last login data in local storage. My app has a list of items. When user presses the button on listTile I save lastLogin info like this

```
List<LastLogin> _loginInfo = [
      LastLogin(fullName: orgUnitList.fullName, loginDate: _loginDate)
    ];

onTap: () {
  _sharedPrefsStore.write(PrefsKeys.lastLogin, _lastLoginDate);
}
```

It works fine, I can see that it saved my data and I can used it. Here comes my problem. When user presses another listTile button it overrides last entry. So my `lastLogin` prefKey only displays last entry. How can I store multiple entries in my prefKey?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `_sharedPrefStore.write` accepts a `String` as new value, you can do this:

```dart
// Get last login
String loginJsonString = _sharedPrefsStore.read(PrefsKeys.lastLogin);
final List loginJsonList = jsonDecode(loginJsonString) as List;
final List<LastLogin> lastLogins = loginJsonList
    .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
    .map(LastLogin.fromJson)
    .toList();

LastLogin? latestLogin;

if (lastLogins.isNotEmpty) {
  latestLogin = lastLogins.last;
}

// Add new login
LastLogin newLogin = LastLogin(fullName: 'fullname', loginDate: 'some date');
lastLogins.add(newLogin);
loginJsonString = jsonEncode(loginJsonList);
_sharedPrefsStore.write(PrefsKeys.lastLogin, loginJsonString);
```

You can modify the code above to suit your needs.